# zip file giving me the archive entry was compressed using an unsupported compression method

Tags: c#, exception, task-parallel-library, unzip

I have a to create a routine that will unzip multiple zip files( average size of the zip will be 2GB) in parallel.   So, I created a function that using TPL to unzip the files.

This works well in principle.   I don't have test data yet so i figured I would make a copy of the zip file that currently exists and rename the files in it and rezip it.  Well, I am getting the following error when I do that:

> the archive entry was compressed using an unsupported compression method

Well please comment on the code as you see fit and why am I getting the error here.

Code:

```
 private static void UnzipfilesInTemp()
       {
           Task[] unzippers = null;
           bool rtn = false;

           //--UNZIP FILES IN TEMPORARY LOCATION
           var TEMP_ZIP_FILES = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(tempPath, "*" + Statement*.zip");
           unzippers = new Task[TEMP_ZIP_FILES.Length];
           unZippedFiles = new string[TEMP_ZIP_FILES.Length];

           lock (thisLock)
           {

               for (int i = 0; i <= TEMP_ZIP_FILES.Length - 1; i++)
               {
                   string filename = TEMP_ZIP_FILES[i];
                   unzippers[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                   {

                       //--UNZIP FILE FOR STATEMENT IMPORTING

                       try
                       {

                           ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(filename, tempPath);
                       }
                       catch (Exception)
                       {
                           //--UNABLE TO UNZIP FILES
                           _coreprocess.AddLogDetailRecord(MSG, false, "");
                           ProcessSuccess = false;
                           ExitAllCode();
                       }



                   });

               }

           }

           Task.WaitAll(unzippers);
           unZippedFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(tempPath, "*" + BANK_NUM + "*.PDF");

       }
```

Comment: Does it behave any differently if you don't do it in a thread? Also, what software created the zip? There are a number of variations on zip out there, and not every decompresser can handle every zip file.

Comment: There are several compression methods supported, and if the method falls outside those supported by the `ZipFile` class in .NET, then you'll see this error. [the WinZip info page](http://www.winzip.com/wz54.htm) has a little bit of information on some of the different compression methods. This is becoming more and more common - I'm seeing a lot of PPMd compressed files come past my desk.

Comment: @Petesh   Thanks.  This helps.  I thihk I am going to write up a little cmd line util to try and create test files and see what happens.